# JavaScript - Put arrays into view model then return model via AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have arrays that are created in my javascript, for example here is how one array is created

```
  $("button").click(function () {
                //var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']", "#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm").val();
                var partArray = []; //for creating json array                
                //looping through trs with class tr_clonePart
                $(".tr_clonePart").each(function () {
                    //for storing qtys and radios of cloned and original
                    var qty_actiontype_cloned = []
                    var datas_cloned = {};
                    var data_original = {}//fro original
                    var qty_actiontype_original = [];
                    //get infos for various fields
                    var p_id = $(this).find("td > a").attr('p-id');
                    var mfg = $(this).find("input.part_mfg").val();
                    var part_name = $(this).find("input.part_name").val();
                    var qty_in_item = $(this).find("input.qty_in_item").val();
                    var item = {};
                    //add values in json objects
                    item["PartID"] = p_id
                    item["MFGNumber"] = mfg
                    item["PartName"] = part_name
                    item["QtyInItem"] = qty_in_item
                    //chcking if part-class is checked or not
                    if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox'].part-class").is(':checked')) {

                        var move_all = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox'].part-class").val();
                        //item["MoveAll"] = move_all
                        item["MoveAll"] = (move_all == "true");
                        var radios = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
                        data_original["action_type"] = radios //adding value of radios in array
                        //item['radios_c'] = radios_c
                        var qty = $(this).find("input.qty").val();
                        data_original["qty"] = qty //adding value of qty in array
                        qty_actiontype_original.push(data_original)
                        item["QtyActionTypeOriginal"] = qty_actiontype_original
                        //item["qty"] = qtys
                    } else {
                        var qty = $(this).find("input.qty").val();
                        //for original data
                        data_original["qty"] = qty
                        var radios = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
                        //for original data
                        data_original["action_type"] = radios
                        qty_actiontype_original.push(data_original)
                        item["QtyActionTypeOriginal"] = qty_actiontype_original
                        //item["MoveAll"] = "false"
                        item["MoveAll"] = (move_all == "false");
                        //looping through cloned trs
                        $(".tr_clonePart_" + p_id).each(function () {

                            var radios_clones = $(this).find("input[type='radio'].radios:checked").val();
                            //puuting value in cloned array
                            datas_cloned["action_type"] = radios_clones

                            console.log(radios_clones)
                            var qty_clones = $(this).find("input.qty").val();

                            datas_cloned["qty"] = qty_clones
                            //push data in cloned array
                            qty_actiontype_cloned.push(datas_cloned)

                        });
                        //push array in cloned json object
                        item["QtyActionTypeCloned"] = qty_actiontype_cloned


                    }
                    //getting other values
                    var onHand = $(this).find("input.OnHand").val();
                    var onWorkOrder = $(this).find("input.onWorkOrder").val();
                    var committed = $(this).find("input.committed").val();
                    var fstk = $(this).find("input.fstk").val();
                    item["OnHand"] = onHand
                    item["OnWorkOrder"] = onWorkOrder
                    item["Committed"] = committed
                    item["FSTK"] = fstk
                    //push json object in array
                    partArray.push(item)

                })
```

But i want to be able to put the 'partArray' into my itemViewModel that looks like this

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }

        public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set; }

    }
```

if it helps here is my itemPartViewModel layout, (all the other ILists have the same layout)

```
 public class ItemPartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string PartID { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public float QtyInItem { get; set; }
        public float Qty { get; set; }
        public bool MoveAll { get; set; }
        public float OnHand { get; set; }
        public float OnWorkOrder { get; set; }
        public float Committed { get; set; }
        public float FSTK { get; set; }

        public QtyActionTypeCloned[] qty_actiontype_cloned { get; set; }
        public QtyActionTypeOriginal[] qty_actiontype_original { get; set; }

        // This is the additional property to contain what user picks
        public PartActionType SelectedActionType { get; set; }
    }
```

So I am wondering how I can put every array that is created, into my itemViewModel and then pass the entire ViewModel into the controller method?

Here is my AJAX

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@IGT.baseUrl/JODetails/SpecialOrderSelection",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data:
                        JSON.stringify({ itemViewModel: myData }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function () {
                        alert('Success!');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error! ');
                    }
                });
```

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess but would it not be

```
var myData = {
    Id: idValue,
    JobId: jobIdValue,
    ItemId: itemIdValue,
    ItemName: itemNameValue,
    MFGNumber: mfgNumberValue,
    Parts: partArray,
    Components: componentArray,
    ComponentParts: componentPartArray,
    ComponentSubComps: componentSubCompsArray,
    SubCompParts: subCompPartsArray,
    SubCompSubComps: subCompSubCompsArray,
    SubCompSubCompParts:subCompSubCompPartsArray
}


var ajaxData = JSON.stringify({myViewModel: myData});
```

Then the post method in the controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        //rest of post method 
    }
```

Also on the client `qty_actiontype_cloned` and `qty_actiontype_original` are arrays.  So I suggest that in your `ItemPartViewModel` you change

```
public QtyActionTypeCloned qty_actiontype_cloned { get; set; }
public QtyActionTypeOriginal qty_actiontype_original { get; set; }
```

to

```
public QtyActionTypeCloned[] qty_actiontype_cloned { get; set; }
public QtyActionTypeOriginal[] qty_actiontype_original { get; set; }
```

Also looks like your client names are not matching the server names.  To fix you either need to change on the client i.e.

```
item["QtyActionTypeOriginal"] = qty_actiontype_original
```

needs to become

```
item["qty_actiontype_original"] = qty_actiontype_original
```

or on the server i.e.

```
public QtyActionTypeOriginal[] qty_actiontype_original { get; set; }
```

needs to become

```
public QtyActionTypeOriginal[] QtyActionTypeOriginal{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test that out

Comment: Where do I place the var my Data in the script? In the javascript? because when I add it in before the ajax it gives me weird unexpected identifier errors that are invisible on my dev screen but show up in my console

Comment: here is the link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291317/javascript-unexpected-identifier-error-message-in-console?noredirect=1#comment111918204_63291317

Comment: And the qty_actiontype_cloned and qty_actiontype_original is returning back as null to the controller within the model

Comment: It is still returning the qty_actiontype_cloned and qty_actiontype_original as null

Comment: ahhh this was my problem. Thanks so much Dave!