# Javascript - Unexpected identifier error message in console

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am getting an unexpected identifier error and I am not sure what is causing it. Here is how I setup 'myData'

```
var myData = {
   Id: @Model.Id,
   JobId: @Model.JobId,
   ItemId: @Model.ItemId, //error on this line in console
   ItemName: @Model.ItemName,
   MFGNumber: @Model.MFGNumber,
   Parts: partArray,
   Components: componentArray,
   ComponentParts: componentPartArray,
   ComponentSubComps: componentSubCompsArray,
   SubCompParts: subCompPartsArray,
   SubCompSubComps: subCompSubCompsArray,
   SubCompSubCompParts: subCompSubCompPartsArray
 }
```

Here is how my itemViewModel is setup

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }

        public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the console showing the error

[image: console]

Why am I getting this error message? If I take out the 'ItemID' field I get an invisible 'unexpected identifier' at the end of the script. So I am not sure what the issue with the myData is?

Comment: ItemId need´s to be a string `"106101-5 STL"`

Comment: @Örvar what do you mean by that?

Comment: It looks like when the `myData` object is being populated that the ItemId property input is a number, hyphen and letters.. Just looks odd and missing quotes..

Comment: What is this `@Model` syntax? It looks like some server-side templating language which is used to build JS code, and that's failing because the values are not properly escaped. And what language is the `ItemViewModel` class written in?

Comment: @Bergi PIC_Program_1._0.Models.ItemViewModel and it's written in C#

Comment: this question needs a razor tag added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right.  You are trying to generate some javascript in your razor.
Say you have this code and someString is a string with the value "some String".  If your razor is this

```
var myString = @someString;
```

then this would be rendered

```
var myString = some String;
```

which is not valid javascript.  To fix this you need to use quotes.  Like this

```
var myString = '@someString';
```

and then this is rendered

```
var myString = 'some String';
```

which is valid javascript.

Only use the quotes though when the value is going to be a string.  Obviously leave the ones that are numbers, bools etc alone.